# Strange div behavior when floated right

Tags: html, css

I am working on a menu bar for my website.

[image: This is how the menu should look - for testing purposes - made in Photoshop]

```css
.main-menu {
  position: fixed;
  left: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: top 200ms;
  transition: top 200ms;
  font-size: 14px;
  display : block;
  overflow: hidden;
}  
.main-menu .left {
  float: left;   
}
.main-menu .right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-menu">
  <div class="left">
    The menu bar of my page
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Right content
  </div>
<div>
```

I need the menu the be `left: 250px;`, but it has the `width` set to `100%`. Since it is fixed, the page won't scroll (and I don't even want that), but the `Text` on the right won't show, since the div takes up more space than the page has. I need the div to take up the remaining space on the page. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean this http://jsfiddle.net/6vf8u8o2/2/ ?

Comment: Actually, no, because that would overlap the content I have from `x=0` to `x=250px`

Comment: i believe u can achieve this using flex where one div you can fix width and 250 and giving other style flex as 1.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if the following works.

```css
.wrap{
   display: flex;
   position:fixed;
   width:100%;
}
.main-menu {
   flex: 1;
   background: #f1f1f1;
   padding-top: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
   padding-left: 8px;
   padding-right: 8px;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   height: 50px;
   top: 0;
   text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: top 200ms;
   transition: top 200ms;
   font-size: 14px;
   display : block;
   overflow: hidden;
}  
.main-menu .left {
   float: left;   
}
.main-menu .right {
   float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div style="width:250px;"></div>
        <div class="main-menu">
      <div class="left">
        The menu bar of my page
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        Right content
      </div>
    <div>
 </div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o7xmk43n/)